# How to verify how good my data is?

Tags: statistics, physics, data-analysis

I'm in an undergrad physics lab right now and I have taken some data.  The theoretical curve should be proportional to $\cos^2(\theta)$.  How can I quantify how close my data values are to this theoretical curve?  Can I linearize it somehow and then let Excel do a least squares type line for me?  Or is there some better way of quantifying how close my data is?  Sorry I haven't taken any statistics and this physics lab doesn't explain anything to me.  Thanks in advance for any answers. :)

Comment: With Internet connection you can check [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions).

Comment: Sorry man, you need a stadistic curse for understand it, try learning a bit of dispersion, correlation , variance, simple covariance, etc. Try wiki, is hard to explain all concepts

Comment: Darn.  I was afraid of that.

Comment: A sadistic curse? That is groovy stats!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose one of your input values is $\theta$ and the experimental value for that $\theta$ is $\hat y.$ The theoretical output value is $y=\cos^2\theta$.  The difference between $\hat y$ and $y$ measures how good the experimental data is for that particular $\theta$ value.

To measure how good the experimental data is overall, you could take the average of these differences over all data points.  Suppose that your experimental data points are $(\theta_1,\hat y_1),(\theta_2,\hat y_2),\ldots,(\theta_n,\hat y_n).$  The corresponding points on the theoretical curve are $(\theta_1,y_1),(\theta_2,y_2),\ldots,(\theta_n,y_n),$ where $y_i=\cos^2\theta_i.$  The average of these differences is then
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|\hat y_i-y_i|$$
This is called the [mean absolute error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error).

Another alternative is to take the square root of the sum of the squares of the errors
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-y_i)^2}$$ 
This is called the [root-mean-square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation).  The formula seems more magical, but is more commonly used in practice (as far as I can tell).

Both of these quantify how close the experimental data is to the theoretical curve.  The smaller either of these values is, the better the experimental data is.

Answer (score 0):

well, first off - I cannot fathom a collection of huge data (by experiments, analytical or empirical) that follows a  $$cos^2(\theta)$$ distribution ! 
naturally most "good" data distributions/collections must follow a  Normal distribution( preferrably 0 mean and standard deviation 1 kind of data) , for large amount of observations.

But I'll leave the validity of your 2nd statement , to you.

Coming to the closeness of data.
For an undergraduate , generally, its very helpful to learn MATLAB.

Its a software, used for many purposes( which you might want to google). And it would be helpfull if you could learn basic statistics,mean , standard deviation ,variance, mean square values , statistical distributions etc. Also some concepts like cross correlation can help too.

But I would stress on you getting to learn to use MATLAB. There are a lot of resources online to help you learn it .

Pertaining to your question , you can get the "goodness" measure or any such parameter about your data and the theoretical curve you want it to follow by using - the curve fitting  module/app of MATLAB/Simulink.
In that you can check the closeness of your data to the your desired model by ensuring SSE (sum of squared residuals) is nearly 0 (it can never be absolute 0 because of random factors contributing to the deviation in the data)

Does that help ?

Comment: Maybe it's not a huge amount of data (I took $360/5=72$ data points) or maybe it's not a distribution.  But if you're curious, the part of the experiment I need to verify first is [Malus's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizer#Malus.27_law_and_other_properties) -- thus the $\cos^2$ function.

Comment: @user234857 So these are not separate measurements of the same quantity, they are measurements of quantities that are related through the same model but each has a different value of the parameter $\theta$ in the model. (That-Kickass-GirL's surprised comment applies to independent measurements of the same quantity.) If you don't have multiple samples for each value of $\theta$, then you should be worried that your measurements might be noisy. That said, if you have mitigated the concern about noisy measurements, then the question boils down to curve fitting, e.g. by least squares regression.

Comment: @That-Kickass-GirL Yes it does help.  I'll try to learn MATLAB and some statistics over the summer so I know what I'm doing for next year's lab.  Thanks.

Comment: @user234857 Note that the sort of regression you should do depends on what your assumption for the form of the curve is. For instance, if you assume the curve is $I_0 \cos^2(\theta)$, then you are only fitting against $I_0$, which is already a linear regression problem (the quantity of interest is a linear function of the parameter $I_0$ that you are trying to find). No linearization is required in this situation. By contrast, fitting to a power law or exponential trend is a nonlinear problem, and is usually handled by linearization.

Comment: @Ian I can actually be pretty confident about my value of $I_0$ (It's very easy to measure reliably).  It's $\theta$ that I am fitting against.

Comment: @user234857 I don't understand the context, then. What is your independent variable and dependent variable, and what theoretical equation should connect them?

Comment: $I$ is the dependent variable, $\theta$ is the independent variable, $I_0$ is a known (measured) constant.  The relation is exactly what you wrote $I=I_0\cos^2(\theta)$.  The experimental data isn't exactly proportional to $\cos^2(\theta)$ -- it's just pretty close.  If I don't need to measure $I_0$ and can find it from the statistical analysis, all the better, but it is easy to measure.

Comment: @user234857 Then actually there is no fitting at all, you are just measuring the error in the fit you have already established in advance. Sorry if I confused you by talking about fitting. But yes, you could choose the best $I_0$ for your data by linear regression, but there might be good reason not to do so (for instance, if your measurement for $\theta=0$ is much more reliable than the rest).

Comment: Ian .. thanks for clarifying my answer !.... but just to be clear  , @Ian , are  you trying to say it should be fitted against $$I_0$$ or $$\theta$$ ? ... shouldn't it be a comparison between measured $$I$$ and  $$I_0 .cos^2(\theta)$$  for each value of $$\theta$$ ? and it won't be linear regression ...it would be non linear regression. either ways SSE is sufficient here though.

Comment: As I was saying to the OP, I think I misunderstood what fitting (if any) was being done in this problem. Indeed I think there is actually no fitting going on at all.